# Which CPU/Mainboard generation really supports TPM 2.0 for Windows 11 regardless of Microsofts list?

Tags: windows, tpm, windows-11, windows-11-preview, ftpm

I'd like to have a list, where i can see supported CPU/MB generations (not concrete models), goes into technical details what kind of TPM (fTPM, dTPM) is required.

Going into detail of technical reality of these MB/CPUs, and if i need a discrete TPM card or if the CPU/MB generation has an embedded/firmware TPM.

Sadly, the list from Microsoft is quite limited: "8th Gen Core an newer".

Answer (score 8):

Glossary:

- TPM: Trusted Platform Module. A Hardware in a modern Windows Computer, which can be used/utilized for security:

  - directly by the OS (Windows and Linux)
  - by other Hardware, as Intel TXT/SMX
- dTPM: discrete TPM 1.0/1.2 or 2.0; a module you (Plug) or the OEM (Plug or solder) needs to add to your main board, usually proprietary modules via a 13, 15, 17, 19 Pin connector (pre 2015)
- fTPM: Firmware TPM; is always TPM 2.0 compatible. A module embedded into the CPU or Chipset. (from 2015 to this day) No need for a dTPM on the mainboard anymore. But dTPM can be used too.
- Intel TXT/SMX: a Intel CPU Extension which **utilizes** a separate dTPM or fTPM; TXT/SMX does **not** contain an fTPM or dTPM
- Intel PTT: intels Hardware implementation of fTPM; embedded/integrated in the Chipset since LGA 1151 (anno 2015)
- AMD PSP: Platform Security Processor, AMDs umbrella Term for any of the Intel equivalents to TXT/SMX, PTT, fTPM, Intel ME

  - fTPM is  build into the CPU/SOC/APU since 2018
  - side note: AMDs fTPM is acutally a [ARM Cortex-A5 TrustZone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Security_extensions)
- TPM 2.0: (usually) includes support for 1.0 and 1.2
- TPM 1.0/1.2: old TPM spec. (Pre 2013)

There are three options:

| General | Intel | AMD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mostly no hw-support for a dTPM not able to run Windows 11 | pre 2013 |  |
| Not officially supported, but should work with Windows 11, if you buy/have a dTPM with TPM 2.0 support A lot of the Mainboards have a proprietary socket for a dTPM A dTPM (or alternatively fTPM) is required! The TPM itself is not included, but **may** be present. Plugged/soldered on the MB by OEM or the user If you have a dTPM you should be able to enable it in BIOS/UEFI and run Windows 11. You should be able order a dTPM for your specific mainboard. Look in the manual for the correct PIN count | since 2013 separate dTPM required None of the **LGA1150** (aka. 4th and 5th Gen Core CPU) Chipsets (H81, C222, B85, C224, Q85, Q87, C226,H87, Z87) and prior have PTT support, hence no embedded/integrated fTPM | since 2016/2017 - separate dTPM required - no embedded fTPM this concerns Zen (1fst gen)/Ryzen 1000 Mainboards |
| official windows 11 support. a fTPM module embedded/integrated into the CPU or Chipset | since 2015 fTPM (which Intel calls PTT) included in every Chipset (except C236) All **LGA1200** (8/9/10/11th gen core CPU) with 400 and 500 chipset have PTT support All (except one) of the **LGA1151** (6/7th gen Core cpu) Chipsets (100, 200, 300, **except C236**) have PTT support | since 2018 fTPM included in every SOC/CPU Socket AM4, "Zen+" (Ryzen 2000), "Zen 2", "Zen 3" and newer contain an embedded fTPM |

Examples for dTPMs you should be able to buy and use it to upgrade your PC:

- [ASRock TPM-S Module (18-1 pin)](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:evL7MMYyI8EJ:https://www.asrock.com/mb/spec/card.asp%3FModel%3DTPM-S%2520Module+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de)
- [ASUS TPM-M R2.0 (14-1 pin)](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/Accessories/TPM-M-R2-0/)
- [Gigabyte GC-TPM2.0 (20-1 pin)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GC-TPM20#ov)
- [MSI TPM 2.0 MODULE (12-1 pin)](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/TPM-20-Module)
- [Intel TPM Module AXXTPME3 for Xeon E3 Systems (14-1 pin)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/55170/tpm-module-axxtpme3.html)

PS:

- Excellent article for further reading: https://pupuweb.com/how-to-enable-tpm20-install-upgrade-windows11/
- excellent tool for checking your compatability: https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11

Side note:

- UEFI is required
- CSM needs to be disabled (CSM="Compatibility Support Module" an option on many UEFI Mainboard to emulate BIOS Boot)
- boot disk needs to be GPT (CSM/BIOS Mode implies MBR; Windows 10 contains the tool MBR2GPT which converts your disk from MBR to GPT within seconds and without dataloss)

My Experience:

I have a 4th Gen Intel CPU (E-1230 v3) with H87 chipset, so no fTPM. I I bought the appropriate dTPM from my Mainboard manufacturer. Upgraded the BIOS/UEFI to the latest beta Version. [And voila TPM 2.0 is available in Windows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3a2M.jpg).

I also needed to:

- convert my disk from MBR to GPT with MBR2GPT.exe
- disable CMS mode in UEFI

Comment: The OS can utilize discrete TPMs without any special CPU support -- it directly uses the SPI or I2C bus, not special CPU instructions, so it doesn't need CPU-level TXT/SMX support for that. It's the motherboard firmware that needs support for TPM initialization (which has different requirements for 1.2 vs 2.0 as well).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'll investigate that topic. Apparently both ways (direct access from software/OS and indirect acces via TXT/SMX) are possible. "The Intel® TXT architecture also provides extensions that access certain chipset
registers and TPM address space."  from https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/guides/intel-txt-software-development-guide.pdf

Comment: That seems like the "indirect access via TXT" is just so that the CPU itself could implement TXT-related features; it doesn't seem to duplicate the regular TPM services available via direct access (such as data sealing and key storage).

Comment: Frankly an exhaustive list is impossible. One of my newer machine's is a 'supported' AMD machine where I can't turn on the fTPU cause there's no option in the bios. There's also a fair number of folks in a bios hacking forum I'm looking at for info trying to 'mod' their systems into working. And There's a few software TPU options that might end up being an option for getting this to work with sufficient demand.

Comment: I see people are already publishing instructions how to doctor the install ISO to by-pass the TPM check.

Comment: @user1686 thanks for your suggestions, i think i've understood it and removed the text which indicated TXT is necessary.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - How you bypass the TPM requirement for an leaked Insider Preview build, is very likely, irrelevant to a formal Insider Preview build or more importantly the eventual RTM build.

Comment: I installed the 21996.1.210529-1541 ISO into a new VirtualBox VM on a host with an i7 4790 cpu which is supposed to be too old, and it installed runs just fine.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Assuming it isn't a laptop, does your M/B have a pin header for a TPM module? (If you can find one for less than $200 as of a few days ago.) The TPM requirement could end up being applicable only to OEMs, and the supported CPU list could be a work in progress.

Comment: It's a SFF machine similar to an NUC I got off AliExpress. Apparently my best bet is hacking the bios . No tpm header and it's a weird manufacturer I cannot find any info on.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Somewhere in Microsoft's hardware requirements PDFs, they explicitly state that VMs will be exempt from some of the requirements (TPM one of them, and I think CPUs as well).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Your ability to run Windows 11 within a Virtual Machine is an irrelevant fact.  Windows 11 does not required TPM 2.0 and Secure Boot if it's ran within virtualized hardware.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Microsoft is due to announce the reason TPM 2.0 is required for Windows 11 this week.  The chances TPM is a OEM only requirement is close to zero.  The chances of them providing a (supported) way to bypass the requirement is greater than zero.

Comment: Even if an exhaustive list is not possible, a breakdown like this that speaks to, at least in theory, the rationale for why a device might or might not work is helpful. The OP is exactly correct in that "intel 8th gen+" is so vague (and so very "modern computing" dumbspeak) as to be unhelpful as a metric.

Comment: @Yorik thanks :)  - I (for example) have a Intel 4th gen CPU and no TPM at all. But my ASrock mainboard has the mentioned connector which is 17th PIN called `TPM2-S` and/or `TPM2-s` (with a small "s"). I've ordered one now and will see, if that works.